# Android OnClick play sound and change button image.

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

I want to create a simple application that has a button with an image (ben1), and when you click the button it plays an audio clip (audiofile) and the image changes to a second image (ben2).

Once the button is no longer clicked the image changes back to the original.

I currently have the below code which plays an audio file when the button is clicked

And below that is code I had from an other app that change the button image when it was clicked.

Can someone assist me with exactly how I would merge theses.

**Play audio File**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundID;
boolean loaded = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer benSoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audiofile);

    Button playbenSound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    playbenSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            benSoundMP.start();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**Change Button Image**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton button;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      button= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
      button.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
        }
        View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_red);

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this, is to set as resource of the button a selector xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_standby"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>
</selector>`

And you don't need to change or add anything to the button listener, on your button declaration on layout, you add this file as the background.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `imgButtonHandler` and add this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_red);
    }
});
```